# Set parent div class in child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have not much knowledge of UI. I have an issue, my jsp generating the markup via logic as below :

```html
Slider
<div id="gridslider" class="jcarousel home ">
   Slide_0
   <div class="slide">
      <div class ="f50">
         Grid Feature
         <div class="feature  " style="background-image: ">
            <div class="content ">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class ="f12">
         Grid Feature
         <div class="feature  " style="background-image: ">
            <div class="content ">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   Slide_1
   <div class="slide">
      <div class ="f100">
         Grid Feature
         <div class="feature  " style="background-image: ">
            <div class="content ">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can see I have some classes like `<div class ="f50">` under `<div class ="side">` and below it there is `<div class="feature  " style="background-image: ">`. I want some logic at `<div class ="side">` level in which all its 
divs like `<div class ="f50">` will move its value, i.e. "f50" to the feature class  `<div class="feature  " style="background-image: ">` will be `<div class="feature f50" style="background-image: ">` and `<div class ="f50">` will be removed, same for other.

Any Idea how can i achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('.feature  ').each(function(){
 $(this).addClass($(this).parent().attr('class'));
 $(this).unwrap();
});
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should refactor that jsp instead, but here is a bit of code that would do your needs in jQuery :)

```
$(function(){

  $('.feature').each(function(){
    //read class from parent
    var classes = $(this).parent().attr('class');

    //add parents class and remove parent  
    $(this).addClass(classes).unwrap();
  });

});
```

Here's a link so you can try it out
http://jsbin.com/pohiqedene/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: previous answer is nearly the same but wont remove the element as you've asked, just it class :)